# How does Ethereum / the EVM know not to execute metadata/auxdata?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, meta-data

I have a contract as such:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract SSimpleStorage {
    uint256 storedNumber;

    function storeNumber(uint256 newNumber) external {
        storedNumber = newNumber;
    }

    function readNumber() external view returns (uint256) {
        return storedNumber;
    }
}
```

And it compiles to bytecode:

```
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060ac8061001e6000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060325760003560e01c8063b6339418146037578063b63d343f146049575b600080fd5b60476042366004605e565b600055565b005b60005460405190815260200160405180910390f35b600060208284031215606f57600080fd5b503591905056fea2646970667358221220111288e4086274ee3fb300e895a6951b5eabae71a4832b2c422ccc5d7622ceeb64736f6c634300080f0033
```

However, we know the last section of the bytecode is the contract metadata:

```
a2646970667358221220111288e4086274ee3fb300e895a6951b5eabae71a4832b2c422ccc5d7622ceeb64736f6c634300080f0033
```

My question is, how does a blockchain like ETH know not to do anything with that metadata? Is it just that it doesn't have any jump destinations? Could you hypothetically execute metadata?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the auxdata/metadata is just unreachable code. It doesn't have any jump destinations that are jumped to by the rest of the code.

It's sort of like having code after a return statement. It just doesn't do anything.